# Better way to perform regex find all

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex to extract some text from a string. Given a string, I am looking to extract the "tags". Tags can be defined in two ways:

1) a single word following an `@` sign e.g. `@tag` should return `tag`

2) multiple words between `@"` and `"` e.g. `@"multiple words tag"` should return `multiple words tag`.

For (1), I have the pattern `\B@\w+` and for (2) the pattern `@"(.*?)"`.

I have several questions:

a) Pattern 1 returns the tag with the `@` still prepended. How can I change the pattern to only return the word without the `@`?

b) How can I combine the patterns into one pattern that can be used in, for instance:

```py
re.findall(pattern, string)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good use-case for a conditional regex:

```
@(")?((?(1)[^"]+|\w+))
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/c1dE81/6).

---

See

```
import re

text = """
lorem ipsum @"multiple words tag"
lorem ipsum @tag 
"""

tags = [m.group(2) for m in re.finditer(r'@(")?((?(1)[^"]+|\w+))', text)]
print(tags)
# ['multiple words tag', 'tag']
```

---

In order to replace the matches and get the tags, use the following code:

```
import re

text = """
lorem ipsum @"multiple words tag"
lorem ipsum @tag 
"""
tags = []
def replacer(match):
    tags.append(match.group(2))
    return ""

text = re.sub(r'@(")?((?(1)[^"]+|\w+))(?(1)")', replacer, text)
print(text)
print(tags)
```

Comment: This doesn't work as `@tag none tags words` which should return just `tag` returns all 4 strings

Comment: @MaxWilkinson: I messed the initial expression up, see the updated answer.

Comment: Is there also a way to remove full match and group 1 from the string?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a)/b):

I would suggest the following regex for python 3.7-3.8:

```
@(?:"((?:\w+\s{1}){0,}\w+)"){0,1}(?:(\w+){0,1})
```

Comment: Why should you need a non-capturing group for `@` ?

Comment: Thank you. No non-capturing group needed. Your regex is shorter than mine. Very elegant indeed. But my regex gives the same result.